# c# Updating datetime column in access

Tags: c#, datetime, ms-access, syntax-error, insert-update

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@constring);
con.Open();
string cmdstring = "UPDATE table SET date=" + DateTime.Parse(datetxt.Text) +" WHERE id ="+id;
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstring,con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I want to update date column which is stored in access database. But it gives me syntax error(missing operator) in query expression '03.03.2016 00:00:00'
In access date column type is Date/Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with :

```
string cmdstring = "UPDATE table SET date='" + DateTime.Parse(datetxt.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyy") +"' WHERE id ="+id;
```

Comment: I changed "#yyyy/MM/dd#" --> "dd/MM/yyyy" then it worked. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it seems a problem in the date format . The solution indicated by Beldi Anouar should funcionarte .

Good luck